# is there any way to limit IFTTT ingredient string?

Tags: if-this-then-that

I am using RSS feed to Email digest applet in IFTTT.

There is one ingredient tag in RSS feed, {{EntryContent}}, that will rendered a full article.

Is there any way in IFTTT applet to reduce the rendered content into just limited number of word or character?

Such as {{EntryContent}, 30, words} to render {{EntryContent}} for just the first 30 words  instead of full article content.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, no, there's no way to change the output of an IFTTT ingredient.

The only other option you can think of is to run through your RSS feed through another service that will do what you want, and use that as your feed. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any services that will abbreviate a full feed like that. (I have encountered some that will do the opposite.)